# i want to add a download link generator to the "mini ajax file upload form" script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

i'm trying to get a download link after a file is uploaded using "mini AJAX file upload form" 
[mini-ajax-file-upload-form](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/)

i am trying to get this script to work with it but all the scipt does is upload it but i get no download link response.

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
    $r = rand(1,100000);
    $filename = $r . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $filename)) {
    echo "<center>";
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Please Rename your file and try again.</center><br>";
      }
  else
  {
  $link="$baseurl/upload/" . $filename;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $filename);
  echo "<center>Direct Download link: <a href=\"$link\">$link</a></center><br>";
```

can someone take a look at "mini AJAX file upload form" for me?

THANX!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the 'upload' directory has write permissions??

Next time, you can try to add these lines at the top of your code

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If move_uploaded_file failed, it will always print out an error with detailed explanation.